# How can I uninstall all packages from one Debian source?

Tags: debian, apt, repository, uninstall

I previously added some external sources to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` but I now want to remove one of them. I also want to:

- remove all packages solely from that source
- revert all packages to versions in my original source(s)
- alternatively, make a list of all packages from this source so I can perform this procedure manually

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on the configuration of the repository you wish to remove, `apt list --installed` might provide enough information to identify packages you need to uninstall or downgrade. Another option, if the repository defines a unique “Origin”, is to use `aptitude search '~i ~Oorigin'` (replacing `origin` as appropriate).

(This is a generic answer; if you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/401604/edit) to specify exactly which source you want to remove, I can add a specific answer.)

Comment: this looks promising, could I get a list of origins somehow?

Comment: Yes, `apt-cache policy` will show you the origins for all your configured repositories (look for `o=` in the output).

Answer (score 4):

Or with dpkg:

`dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'|grep -v /var/lib/dpkg/status| sed -e 's/://'|awk '{printf "%-40s %-36s %-36s %-16s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}' | grep -i yourkeyword`

For example

`dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'|grep -v /var/lib/dpkg/status| sed -e 's/://'|awk '{printf "%-40s %-36s %-36s %-16s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}' | grep -i multimedia`

returns:

```
audacious                                1:3.8.2-dmo1                         http://www.deb-multimedia.org        stretch/main     
audacious-plugins                        1:3.8.2-dmo1                         http://www.deb-multimedia.org        stretch/main     
audacious-plugins-data                   1:3.8.2-dmo1                         http://www.deb-multimedia.org        stretch/main    
snipp
```

This shows me the packages from deb-multimedia.org. Same result with `dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t\t${Package}\n'  | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'|grep -v /var/lib/dpkg/status| sed -e 's/://'|awk '{printf "%-40s %-36s %-36s %-16s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}' | egrep -i multimedia`